# DHTMLX Scheduler for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dhtmlx

I want to use DHTMLX for asp.net and not for mvc. I can only find tutorials to use them in mvc. Is there any tutorials to guide for using in asp.net 3.5. I'm using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tutorials for asp.net as well, in both C# and VB.Net

http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/07/09/vb-scheduler-tutorial.aspx

http://scheduler-net.com/docs/common_application_with_scheduler.html

They are done in visual studio 2010, but i think there will be no problems with that

Comment: I had tried this but I get the following errors:Error1 Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).Error 2 'ASP.default_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found to override Error 3 'ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)': no suitable method found to override Error 4 'ASP.default_aspx' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable'

Comment: Default.aspx is supposed to be a Web Form. It already implements IHttpHandler interface, since it is inherited from System.Web.UI.Page, so you shouldn't do it manually.
If you are following c# tutorial, you should have 3 files for http requests(one Web Form and two Generic Handlers):
1)Default.aspx - codebehind is described in 'Step 6' of the tutorial;
2)Data.ashx - 'Step 7';
3)Save.ashx - 'Step 8';

Comment: In the step9 of the tutorial it has said to replace the control named bodycontent. I can't find that control. Where should I copy it?

Comment: you may paste content of 'asp:Content'(without asp tag itself) item inside the body tag of Default.aspx page.

Comment: Thank you.I followed the exact same steps in the tutorials but I'm still getting the 4 errors I got before. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure that Inherits attribute of Default.aspx is pointing to the right class name(including the namespaces).
Error1 might happen when the same class name is used in different codebehind pages, check if there is any name conflicts.